# Should the updated posterior for a Poisson distribution be discretized if based on the Gamma distribution as the prior?

Tags: bayesian, poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution, discrete-data, conjugate-prior

I know that the Gamma distribution is the conjugate prior of the Poisson distribution, such that given $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that describe the prior distribution, the posterior distribution is $Gamma(\alpha + n\bar{y}, \beta + n)$, where $n$ is the total number of observations and $\bar{y}$ is the mean of the observations.

Of course, the Poisson distribution is discrete; the Gamma distribution, however, is continuous. **My very basic question is, is it appropriate to discretize the Gamma posterior distribution by passing in simply discrete values?** E.g., does Gamma(2) yield the probability of 2 counts, or is the probability of two counts given instead by something like Gamma(1.5 - 2.5)?

For context, I'm working on a Python package for Bayesian A/B testing and am hoping to discretize my [Poisson plots](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PlatosTwin/bayes_ab/main/examples/plots/poisson_distributions_example.png).

Answer (score 1):

When $X\sim\mathcal P(\lambda)$, a conjugate family of priors on $\lambda\in\mathbb R^*_+$ is the Gamma family, $\lambda\sim\mathcal G(\alpha,\beta)$ since$$\lambda|x\sim\mathcal G(\alpha+x,\beta+1)$$

The fact that the Poisson $P(\lambda)$ distribution has a countable support, $\mathbb N$, does not restrict the range of the possible values of $\lambda$, $\mathbb R^*_+$. Therefore, there is no argument for discretising the support of the prior/posterior distribution.